# How do you solve recursion which are not void

Tags: c, recursion

Suppose that a second stock broker can make only one purchase, but can
sell it on any day afterwards, that is, the stock broker can purchase the stock on some day
i (0 <= i <= n - 2), and can sell it on any day from day i + 1 to day n - 1.
Write a function
double get_max_profit(double prices[], int n)
that returns the maximum profit that this second stock broker can make given an array
prices and its size n as the input. The function should return 0 if the maximum profit is
less than or equal to 0.
For example:
• If prices = {1.0, 5.1, 7.3, 9.4, 4.7, 8.0, 15.0, 6.2} and n = 8, the function should return 14.0. The stock broker should purchase the stock on day 0 and sell it
on day 6, where the maximum profit made is prices[6] - prices[0] = 15.0 - 1.0
= 14.0.

I tried recursion in this but its not giving the last value which is required for this question like it gives 9.1 but in the end prints zero

```
double get_max_profit(double prices[], int n){
    static int day = 0;
    static double max_profit = 0.0;
    printf("the profit is %lf the day is %d\n", max_profit, day);
    if (day >= n-1){
        if (max_profit <=0){
            return 0;
        }
        return max_profit;
    }
    for (int i = day; i < n; i++){
        if (day+1 >= n){
            if (max_profit <=0){
                return 0;
            }
            return max_profit;
        }
        double profit = prices[i] - prices[day];
        if (profit > max_profit){
            max_profit = profit;
        }

    }
    day = day +1;
    get_max_profit(prices, n);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double prices[] =  {2.1, 5.3, 7.7, 9.8, 1.2, 10.3, 5.0};
    int n = 7;
    double max_lim = get_max_profit(prices, n);
    printf("maximum profit is %lf \n", max_lim);
}
```

Comment: When you reach the end of the `get_max_profit`, shouldn't you be returning something? What do you *think* you should return?

Comment: On another note, the implementation of your algorithm is flawed. What happens if you want to call `get_max_profit` multiple times? How would you reset those `static` variables?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you seem to be missing a return, the recursive call does not return in the end and I am humbled by the fact that the function still outputs the correct value when using the gcc as a compiler. You can not rely on this because it is UB, still, I did not check weather your algorithm is correct or not, it just gives the output that you expect. Secondly your code does give me the expected result that you posted. Lastly your algorithm is flawed because if you call it more than once on a different dataset it will retain the static value of those variables, possibly giving an unexpected result (If the second dataset has lower values for example).

As pointed out in the comments, when you compile your C code, if your compiler supports it please consider using the -Wall and -pedantic (I personally prefer -pedantic-errors) options that can save you a lot of troubles when searching for this kind of bugs.

Comment: "I do not understand if that makes the difference or not." - it surely does. if a non void function doesn't return a value it invokes UB even if tha value wasn't used afterwards (but it is). UB means that anything could happen including that you get the expected value that might still lie somewhere on the stack - it seems that this is what you have experienced

Comment: Yes, I was puzzled by the fact that the code "worked" on gcc without it, I never saw UB being "useful" lets say

Comment: Inf fact that's the worst case of "usefulness" I could think of because it may hide errors for a long time until .....

Comment: Edited the answer to make what I wanted to express more clear but yeah, I expected the gcc to complain to this when using the -pedantic option (like I always do) but no, not even a little warning.

Comment: there is wa warning if you use -Wall too (another option you should use always): x.c:28:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]